How to correctly simulate splitting in blackjack
I'm writing a probabilistic simulator for blackjack that returns the best action and expected profit for a given hand, dealer up card, and unseen cards (by calculating all possible scenarios, not monte carlo simulation).
A common rule in blackjack is that you can only split a hand up to 3 times. Splitting more than once is hard to simuate exactly. So to simplify I thought of only allowing one split. Getting a slighly incorrect expected profit is acceptable but a wrong action isn't. So I was wondering, is it possible that splitting up to once is worse than another action (e.g. double) but if we can split up to 3 times then the expected profit is higher than said action (double in this case)?
Also, how can I correctly simulate multiple splits (for a correct expected profit and a correct action if this causes a problem)?
To explain the problem more, let's say we have two 9s and we split them (so we have 2 splits remaining). What I am currently doing is calculating the expected profit of a single 9 card without being able to split again and multiplying it by 2 (as we have two hands). The problem is the two hands have a common split count. Its not like each hand can be split a further 2 times. The possible scenarios are:
A: Hand 1: 0 splits, Hand 2: 0 splits
B: Hand 1: 0 splits, Hand 2: 1 splits (same as D)
C: Hand 1: 0 splits, Hand 2: 2 splits (same as F)
D: Hand 1: 1 splits, Hand 2: 0 splits (same as B)
E: Hand 1: 1 splits, Hand 2: 1 splits
F: Hand 1: 2 splits, Hand 2: 0 splits (same as C)
And in case C (and F respectively) hand 2 will be split in hand 3 and 4.
Then either hand 3 or hand 4 will be split again.
So right now I am using profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, 0 splits remaining). Should I use profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, max 0 splits remaining), profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, max 1 split remaining), and profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, max 2 splits remaining)?
I can probably get the chances of each scenario occurring in my simulations (even though I am not sure how at the moment).
I asked this question here, because I'm looking for statistics help of how to simuate this scenario, and not help in writing the code for my program.
EDIT:
In max 1 split, we simply split the hand, and as there are no remaining splits. We use expected profit = profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, 0 splits remaining) * 2.
In max 2 split, We split the had, and as there is only 1 split remaining, we allocate it to one hand (since this is a probabilistic simulation it doesn't matter which hand). We then use expected profit = profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, 0 splits remaining) + profit(hand, dealer up card, cards unseen, 1 split remaining).
I'm just trying to figure out how to do the same for max 3 splits.
Also, after splitting once, whether the first hand splits twice, or both hands split once doesn't matter and has the same expected value.

I find your posted question to be both outstanding and relevant to this forum.  However, since my reaction involves sharing my (professional) programming experience, rather than math analysis, I am confining my response to the comments.  ...see next comment

Your posted question actually is a small part of a broader question: how do you sanity check a proposed algorithm?  In my opinion, the best way to do this is to write a separate program that actually loops through each of the $~\displaystyle \binom{52}{2}~$ pairs of cards that might be dealt to the dealer, and for each such pair, loops through each of the $~\displaystyle \binom{50}{2}~$ pairs of cards that might be the first two cards dealt to the player.  ...see next comment

Then, when analyzing such situations as whether to hit on $~12~$ when the dealer's up-card is a $~6,~$ try both options to determine which is more profitable.  The exact same approach should be used to determine whether to split once, depending on the rank of the splitting card versus the dealer's up-card, and whether to split a 2nd, 3rd, or 4th time.   ...see next comment

The difficulty with my previous comments is that a vanilla pc will routinely handle $~10^7~$ distinct cases ok, but will probably be too time consuming when faced with (for example) $~5 \times 10^8~$ distinct cases.  So, how is this difficulty to be overcome?

My approach, in such a situation is to reduce the deck to (for example) $~32~$ cards, by assuming that the ranks of $~2~$ through $~6~$ do not exist.  Then, the algorithm has to be similarly adjusted, based on the reduced deck.  Then, you should be able to perform a full sanity-check on the computed probabilities, for any situation that requires a decision.  ...see next comment

Also, I strongly advise using a book like "Beat The Dealer" (Thorp) to provide a starting strategy for your algorithm, that you can then fine tune.  In my previous comments, I have assumed that if you have made no analytical mistake in the reduced deck algorithm, then there is a reasonable chance that your full deck algorithm is also accurate.

Presumably in the 3-split situation you have different cases, though?  I.e. if you're dealt 77, and decide to split, say those turn into 7K and 77 then all the splits go onto that second hand (if you choose to keep splitting), versus turning that into another 77 and 77, where you might decide to play one and split the other (where we're basically in the case above) versus splitting both and using up all your splits (and playing them out without any splits).
